# Rewriting php in Grails - Totally stuck!

Tags: php, javascript, grails

I have to re-write a few php pages in in Grails (don't ask why!).  I have never done any php, so it's proving a little tricky.

Basically I have a html page which has a function in it that is executed every 60 seconds, and that .js creates a new XMLHttpRequest which then does xmlHttp.open("GET", "myphpfile.php", true);

I can get the .js to be called from the gsp no problem at all - but what on earth do I do with the php? I assume I could create a service which would do something similar, but can that be accessed from the .js?

Please help - I am totally stuck!

Comment: All I understood from your question was, "I am rewriting some PHP in Grails, do I need to create something in Grails that does the same thing as the PHP"?

Comment: yea i have to say, very vague and confusing question

Comment: Agree. The question is "teach me php". I think should be closed.

Comment: thanks! the reason it's very vague and confused is because I am very confused!! I didn't write the php, the guy who did is not available to ask him what the code does and I don't know the first thing about php, so i'm trying my best to pick it apart...

Comment: Ben - you're kind of there, I basically need to know is there a way I can incorporate the PHP code into my grails app, or should it be re-written in groovy or something else?

Comment: rose, that's an entirely new question, post that one instead or rewrite this one with _concrete_ doubts about the php script functioning.

Answer (score 2):

Work out what the thing's meant to do, draw some pretty UML, write some documentation, then dump the PHP.

Unless you properly understand what the system as a whole is meant to do, you'll end up trying to do PHP-style stuff in Grails which is a very bad idea. Writing it from scratch in Grails will let you use proper Groovy tricks (closures etc) and it will end up a better system.

You'll also be left with some documentation, which is always nice.